# Unable to access items of an IQueryable<T> by index

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I'm new to c#. I'm attempting to use what ought be a list(?) produced by a linq query to build a table on an ordering form.  Part of that involves referencing a specific item in that list as below:

```
using (CellOrderingDBEntities db = new CellOrderingDBEntities())
{
    var AccessoryItems = from AccessoryDescription in db.Accessories
                         join HardwareID in db.HardwareTypes
                             on AccessoryDescription.HardwareType equals HardwareID.HardwareID
                         where AccessoryDescription.DateRetired == null
                         select AccessoryDescription;

    List<Device> DevicesList = (List<Device>)Session["DevicesList"];

    Guid AccessoriesOrder = (from ServiceID in db.TypeOfServices
                                where ServiceID.ServiceType == "Accessories Order"
                                select ServiceID.ServiceID).FirstOrDefault();

    //This Int is used to build the accessories table
    int AccessoryRows = AccessoryItems.Count();

    if (SType == AccessoriesOrder)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r <= AccessoryRows; r++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                int ai = 0;
                int ri = 0;

                tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + r + "Col_" + c;
                if (c == 0)
                {
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                }
                else if (c == 1)
                {
                    cell.Text = AccessoryItems[ai];
                    ai++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm stuck with this error though:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Data.Accessory>'
```

I've tried converting it to a list of strings but for reasons I do not understand why it won't let me access the `IQueryable` by index.

Comment: And if someone knows a good source for wrapping my head around types, I think that's what I'm not getting as I've been banging my head against this, I'll take it.  Many thanks!

Comment: You might find it easier to use this syntax: `foreach (var ai in AccessoryItems)` instead this: `for (int r = 0; r <= AccessoryRows; r++)` if you don't need `r` for anything other than indexing `AccessoryItems`

Comment: As far as good LINQ resources are concerned: Download LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) and play around with it. (I can also recommend C# 4.0/5.0 in a Nutshell by J. & B. Albahari btw.) Also I would recommend that you learn about the difference between local (cf. IEnumerable<T>) and interpreted queries (cf. IQueryable<T>) and LINQ's deferred mode of execution. Once you have understood these concepts things will become much clearer.

Comment: Linq operations use deferred execution, so items are only retrieved as you request them. Accessing an item by index would mean also reading through all the previous items first, which is of course very inefficient if you do this more than once. If you load the items into a collection first (i.e. by appending `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to the end of your query), you can then access your items by index.

Comment: In addition to the aforementioned C# 4.0/5.0 in a Nutshell and LINQPad suggestions I would also recommend [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
                    var AccessoryItems = from AccessoryDescription in db.Accessories
                                     join HardwareID in db.HardwareTypes
                                     on AccessoryDescription.HardwareType equals HardwareID.HardwareID
                                     where AccessoryDescription.DateRetired == null
                                     select AccessoryDescription;

                List<Accessory> AIL = AccessoryItems.ToList();
```

And this in the for loop:

```
cell.Text = (string) AIL[ai].AccessoryDescription;
```

And it works!

Comment: This query isn't specifying an order, so the items coming back are not in any defined order.  Indexing such a collection isn't really meaningful.  This means there's a real design flaw here; you probably shouldn't be needing to index into the query results at all.

Comment: Can you expound as to the nature of the flaw for me?  Once the query runs the order shouldn't change as I iterate through the result and for what I'm using it for I'm not sure I need the order to be specific?  Many thanks.

Comment: If your goal is simply to iterate through the entire result set then you simply don't need to access items by index.  You can just use a `foreach` instead of a `for` to access all items if that's your goal.

Comment: My understanding from what I'd read was that you couldn't use a foreach loop when building a table?  That is, all the examples I saw said to use a for loop for it?  I initially wanted to use a foreach actually. (And thanks for helping me understand this @Servy!)

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for putting up with what I'm sure are noobish questions.  I'll see if I can figure out how to do it that way then.  Seems like a better way to approach it. How do I give you rep, mark your comments useful, etc...?

Comment: Don't bother.  Comment upvotes don't really mean anything, and I'm not motivated enough to post an answer (and am at the rep cap for the day anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338725.aspx) to access an element at a specific point in a sequence.  So, replace:

```
cell.Text = AccessoryItems[ai];
```

with

```
cell.Text = AccessoryItems.ElementAt(ai) as String;
```

Comment: Same problem.  That just gets this error. :/
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Data.Accessory' to 'string'

It's a data type out of entity Framework.

Comment: Can you convert the type to a string using the as keyword?  (i.e. cell.Text = AccessoryItems.ElementAt(ai) as String;)  Note: ["the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx) so you may need to check for null values.

Comment: I just get a different error.

Cannot convert type 'Data.Accessory' to 'string' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: That's a problem with the Accessory class, Brad's answer is still correct. If you [override ToString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx) in your Accessory class you'd then fix the conversion error. Compiler can't automatically convert your class to a string without your help.